# Detect walls and prevent player from jumping on them

Tags: game-engine, collision

My main goal is to have the best jumping experience - (Keep jumping up and down when spacebar is held down, longer jumps when spacebar is held longer), where there is no wall jumps.

Currently, minus a few features I kinda wanted to have, you can only jump (With the Force Motion) only when the spacebar is pressed, in a collision with an object (Walls too). This creates the ability to wall jump, which I do not want. Removing the Collision sensor makes things worse, where you can keep jumping in the air to space.

[image]

My question is, how do I use the collision sensor (if it's a good way), and to detect/prevent the player from jumping up walls?

[image]

Comment: Check my edited answer, there is the blend to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

First your problem was that you set the ray sensor range to a kilometers (100000.00), set it to 1 or 2 (1.00), also there is no objects with "walls" propety in your file and the ray should look for ground, i set the higer floating ground to wall and you not able to jump over it, the other i change from ground to floatingGround property so this way the ray's and collisions sensors will not add 2 times the force of jumping when the player is over 2 grounds and add another set of ray and collitions sensors and motion actuator  to jump over the floating grounds.

[image]

**Before edit**

Use a `ray sensor property ground` combined with the kerboard sensor and `collision sensor property wall`.
[image]

PD. Its late here and this gif take to much lol.

Comment: I set it up like you have shown, but for some reason, the Ray sensor is preventing jumping. Also, does this work if I want a cube where it's sides are walls, and the top is ground?

Comment: Increese the range distance, the idea is that when the player jump and it higher than the range in the ray sensor the player will just fall, also make sure that the axis is -z (negative) in the ray sensor.

Comment: In  test that i made the ground is below the player and was able to jump higer and able to make doble jump. if you want doble ground over and below the player all you doing is wrong, firts the player will need to be not affected by the world gravity and need to set some sort of doble gravity from the 2 grounds for that the player physics should be static and you need to calculate the forces applies and update the player position with thats calculations.

Comment: What way do you recommend to create a jumping thing like this, that will not double jump, and will not jump off of walls?

Comment: This method is only working for some couple of seconds, or distance, because after some time, whenever and only when I'm above or on a ground object, I can fly jump.

Comment: Could you provide your blend file, the prefered way is [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), would be easy for me to work over your file. [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/96997/edit) and paste the resulting link in your question

Comment: File added. I changed a few things since, but the same thing occurs after some time or distance, not sure.

Comment: That works! Thanks! A follow-up question, why do the three dots upper buttons have to be checked? What's their purpose?

Comment: Those 3 points is to activate "true level triggering", which means that the sensor will run every frame, if not checked the sensor only run the first frame.